Performance issue in flutter with ProgressIndicator on windows
Hi I'm having issues with the performance of CircularProgressIndicator() on windows, when using this widget the CPU usage goes up a lot. I tried in the following set ups:
intel(R) Xeon(R) Bronze 3204 CPU @ 1.90GHz
Loading 3 seconds (60% of CPU usage)
intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9759H CPU @ 2.59 GHz
Loading 3 seconds (10% of CPU usage)
Has anyone else had this issue and knows how to solve it?
I try it creating a blank flutter app with just the progress indicator and the spike is not as heavy but still takes a (40%) usage on the intel Xeon.
The example code:
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text("Demo"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Edit: added images showing the performance overlay screen and the task manager



what does performance overlay show?

I added images showing the performance overlay and the task manager

this is because you run it in debug mode: i made similar code on linux desktop and while in debug mode i had 32-37% in release it was 18-20%

The images are in debug mode in my machine that has the i7-9759H. But the 60% CPU usage on the Xeon(R) Bronze 3204 machine is in release mode.

to be precise: you run your app as a windows desktop application?

Sorry, yes it's a windows desktop app.
